# PHP: how do I show contents based on time and date?

Tags: php

I need to show contents based on a specific date and time in a php page. I need to show content1 upto a certain date, content2 for a limited time (between 2 defined dates), and content3 after the expiry date and time.
Moreover, I need the possibility of changing the timezone, so the time should be provided by the server.

What I got so far is the following:

```
<?php 
$exp_date = "2009-07-20";
$exp_date2 = "2009-07-27";
$todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);
$expiration_date2 = strtotime($exp_date2);
if ($expiration_date > $today)
{ ?>
<!-- pre-promotion week content -->
<?php } else if ($expiration_date2 > $today) { ?>
<!-- promotion week content -->
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- expired/post-promotion week content -->
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that this script takes into account only the date and not the time.

Comment: `2009`??? Any ways, it's more complicated than that. You will need the time for the user's location and not your server's time.

Comment: `script takes into account only the date and not the time`. Probably that's because you are not using time.

Comment: @HamZa - It depends. If you only want your local timezone this should suffice. Users in other timezones will then be able to view content before/later than others.

Comment: @HamZa: The timezone has to be set by me.

Comment: @ElonThan: thank you for pointing out something obvious. I did not know how to use time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the built-in DateTime objects:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

You should also be setting the timezone:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Or you can set the timezone per object:

```
$exp_date = new DateTime("2009-07-20", new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
$exp_date2 = new DateTime("2009-07-27", new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
$today = new DateTime();
if($today < $exp_date) {
   /*...*/
} elseif($today < $exp_date2) {
   /*...*/
} else {
   /*...*/
}
```

Note: I purposefully used two different timezones, to show that you can have your server in one zone, and work with dates from other zones. For example:

```
$ny = new datetime('2015-02-11 05:55:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$la = new datetime('2015-02-11 02:55:00', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
var_dump($ny == $la); // bool(true)
```

Comment: If you provide a date string without a time component, midnight is assumed (i.e. 00:00:00)

Comment: This worked very well. The explanation is also very clear. It was more simple than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend the format used in the `date()` function to include hours, minutes or even seconds (if you want that precision) with the following addition.

```
/*
 * Check the documentation for the date() function to view
 * available format configurations.
 *
 * H - hours 24 format
 * i - minutes with leading zero
 * s - seconds with leading zero
 */
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

When this is used with the `strtotime()` function, you should get a pretty precise UNIX timestamp.